# Get the XML entity passed in body - HTTP Put method in Android

Tags: android, http, entity, put

I wanted to retrieve the XML entity passed in body of HTTP Put method. I used the below code,

```
DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
conn.bind(serverSocket.accept(), new BasicHttpParams());
HttpRequest request = conn.receiveRequestHeader();
conn.receiveRequestEntity((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request);
HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

I could get the norma strings, but when trying to pass the XML entity, I could not even see the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVICE_EPR);          
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(SOAPRequestXML,HTTP.UTF_8);

se.setContentType("text/xml");  
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(se);  

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = 
(BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);

response.put("HTTPStatus",httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
```

Comment: I don't want to send the request..the entity is being passed by other server...i just wanted to consume that in my application.

Answer (score 0):

PFB the solution,

```
DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
params = new BasicHttpParams();
conn.bind(socket, params);

//Extracting the information from the requested URI
HttpRequest request = conn.receiveRequestHeader();
conn.receiveRequestEntity((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request);
HttpEntity httpEntity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity();

if(httpEntity != null){
  InputStream instream = httpEntity.getContent();
  try {
    // do something useful
    String myString = IOUtils.toString(instream, "UTF-8");
    Log.e(TAG,">>>> http body > "+myString);
 } finally {
    instream.close();
 }
```

}

Don't put any log or print statements using the data you received, I was getting 'Content already consumed' exception. I had used several logs using the httpEntity i received and that was causing the problem for me. I commented those(marked yellow) and started working.

PF the Apache doc for reference,

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/pdf/httpcore-tutorial.pdf